# Why is After Update DSUM Before Update Value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subForm, aContinuous Form, filtered by the field JobItemId, that has a field Price, after price is updated I wish to determine the new total of Prices for JobItemId and pass this for processing elsewhere.

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Price_AfterUpdate()
   Dim TotalCost As Currency
   Dim strFilter As String
   strFilter = "[JobItemID] = " + Str(JobItemID.Value)
   TotalCost = DSum("[Price]", Me.Recordset.Name, strFilter)
   Me.Parent.Total = TotalCost
   Me.Parent.Update_FinalPrice
End Sub
```

I set a watch on TotalCost so that I could verify the value that was being passed, and found that the total was the value before the update. Why is this so, and what do I need to do to get the correct after update total?

Comment: Are you certain you need to store this data in the parent record, given that it's calculable from the child records at any time?

Comment: I push the total up to the parent and then it is multiplied by a margin for the final amount. The problem was that the computed value does not have an event to trigger a cascading update of the final cost, as you saw in my other question. So in some ways this is just a work around for that problem.

Comment: The usual way to get totals out of subform is to have a hidden control in the subform's footer (i.e., 0 height for the control and the footer) with a Sum() on the appropriate field, and then refer to that control from the parent form. That will update reliably (though you may see it cascading onscreen as you move from one record to the next in the parent form).

Comment: That approach is fine when I only have one subform, I have five child tables and sometimes two subforms that are totalled, with this I store the total to the DB. It all depends on the sub-type of the parent table. I know what you're saying and I'll have another think about it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ack, subtypes/supertypes. I long ago concluded that those were problematic because to see a list of all of them together required either UNION or a whole bunch of really inefficient LEFT JOINs. That is, I tend to avoid subtype/supertype structures whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is firing in the AfterUpdate event for the control.  You need to move it to the AfterUpdate event for the form (ie, `Form_AfterUpdate`).

DSum operates on the records committed to the database, but even though your price has been updated in the AfterUpdate event for the Price control, it has not yet been committed to the database (Access indicates this by showing the writing pencil in the record selector).  Immediately after the updated record is committed the Form_AfterUpdate event fires.

Comment: Thank you I had worked around it by doing a refresh! This is obviously the right way to do it.